# Uimenucontroller controller not responding to touch

Tags: uiwebview, first-responder, uimenucontroller

I have a uimenucontroller that I am using on a uiwebview. The menu controller works fine on simple text websites however on larger websites i.e. http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/giada-de-laurentiis/grilled-chicken-with-basil-dressing-recipe/index.html my custom menu item will not respond to touches. When tapped it highlights blue briefly then back to black, the menu is still displayed and myAction is nevere called. Sometimes if I click rapidly othe menu controller it will respond so I believe it may be something to do with the responder chain and or the size of the web page. I initialize the menu controller as follows:

```
// in view did appear:  
UIMenuItem *item1 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item1" action:@selector(myAction)];  
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:item1]];


-(void)myAction 
{  
//do something  
}
```

Thank you! I have been stumped by this for 2 weeks and am out of ideas...